# Loading sklearn model in Java. Model created with DNNClassifier in python

Tags: java, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, sklearn-pandas

The goal is to open in Java a model created/trained in python with `tensorflow.contrib.learn.learn.DNNClassifier`.

At the moment the main issue is to know the name of the "tensor" to give in java on the session runner method.

I have this test code in python :

```
    from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow.contrib.learn as learn
import numpy as np
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from tensorflow.contrib import layers
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.utils import input_fn_utils
from tensorflow.python.ops import array_ops
from tensorflow.python.framework import dtypes
from tensorflow.python.util.compat import as_text

print(tf.VERSION)

df = pd.read_csv('../NNNormalizeData-out.csv')

inputs = []
target = []

y=0;    
for x in df.columns:
    if y != 35 :
        #print("added %d" %y)
        inputs.append(x)
    else :
        target.append(x)
    y+=1

total_inputs,total_output = df.as_matrix(inputs).astype(np.float32),df.as_matrix([target]).astype(np.int32)

train_inputs, test_inputs, train_output, test_output = train_test_split(total_inputs, total_output, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

feature_columns = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("", dimension=train_inputs.shape[1],dtype=tf.float32)]
#target_column = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("output", dimension=train_output.shape[1])]

classifier = learn.DNNClassifier(hidden_units=[10, 20, 5], n_classes=5
                                 ,feature_columns=feature_columns)

classifier.fit(train_inputs, train_output, steps=100)

#Save Model into saved_model.pbtxt file (possible to Load in Java)
tfrecord_serving_input_fn = tf.contrib.learn.build_parsing_serving_input_fn(layers.create_feature_spec_for_parsing(feature_columns))  
classifier.export_savedmodel(export_dir_base="test", serving_input_fn = tfrecord_serving_input_fn,as_text=True)


# Measure accuracy
pred = list(classifier.predict(test_inputs, as_iterable=True))
score = metrics.accuracy_score(test_output, pred)
print("Final score: {}".format(score))

# test individual samples 
sample_1 = np.array( [[0.37671986791414125,0.28395908337619136,-0.0966095873607713,-1.0,0.06891621389763203,-0.09716678086712205,0.726029084013637,4.984689881073479E-4,-0.30296253267499107,-0.16192917054985334,0.04820256230479658,0.4951319883569152,0.5269983894210499,-0.2560313828048315,-0.3710980821053321,-0.4845867212612598,-0.8647234314469595,-0.6491591208322198,-1.0,-0.5004549422844073,-0.9880910165770813,0.5540293108747256,0.5625990251930839,0.7420121698556554,0.5445551415657979,0.4644276850235627,0.7316976292340245,0.636690006814346,0.16486621649984112,-0.0466018967678159,0.5261100063227044,0.6256168612312738,-0.544295484930702,0.379125782517193,0.6959368575211544]], dtype=float)
sample_2 = np.array( [[1.0,0.7982741870963959,1.0,-0.46270838239235024,0.040320274521029376,0.443451913224413,-1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,0.36689718911339564,-0.13577379160035796,-0.5162916256414466,-0.03373651520104648,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.786999801054777,-0.43856035121103853,-0.8199093927945158,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-0.1134921695894473,-1.0,0.6420892436196663,0.7871737734493178,1.0,0.6501788845358409,1.0,1.0,1.0,-0.17586627413625022,0.8817194210401085]], dtype=float)

pred = list(classifier.predict(sample_2, as_iterable=True))
print("Prediction for sample_1 is:{} ".format(pred))

pred = list(classifier.predict_proba(sample_2, as_iterable=True))
print("Prediction for sample_2 is:{} ".format(pred))
```

A model_saved.pbtxt file is created.

I try to load this model in Java with the following code :

```
    public class HelloTF {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SavedModelBundle bundle=SavedModelBundle.load("/java/workspace/APIJavaSampleCode/tfModels/dnn/ModelSave","serve");
        Session s = bundle.session();

        double[] inputDouble = {1.0,0.7982741870963959,1.0,-0.46270838239235024,0.040320274521029376,0.443451913224413,-1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,0.36689718911339564,-0.13577379160035796,-0.5162916256414466,-0.03373651520104648,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.786999801054777,-0.43856035121103853,-0.8199093927945158,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-0.1134921695894473,-1.0,0.6420892436196663,0.7871737734493178,1.0,0.6501788845358409,1.0,1.0,1.0,-0.17586627413625022,0.8817194210401085};
        float [] inputfloat=new float[inputDouble.length];
        for(int i=0;i<inputfloat.length;i++)
        {
            inputfloat[i]=(float)inputDouble[i];
        }
        Tensor inputTensor = Tensor.create(new long[] {35}, FloatBuffer.wrap(inputfloat) );

        Tensor result = s.runner()
                .feed("input_example_tensor", inputTensor)
                .fetch("dnn/multi_class_head/predictions/probabilities")
                .run().get(0);


         float[] m = new float[5];
         float[] vector = result.copyTo(m);
         float maxVal = 0;
         int inc = 0;
         int predict = -1;
         for(float val : vector) 
         {
             System.out.println(val+"  ");
             if(val > maxVal) {
                 predict = inc;
                 maxVal = val;
             }
             inc++;
         }
         System.out.println(predict);



    }
}
```

I get the error on the  .run().get(0); line  :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.tensorflow.TensorFlowException: Output 0 of type float does not match declared output type string for node _recv_input_example_tensor_0 = _Recv[_output_shapes=[[-1]], client_terminated=true, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device_incarnation=3663984897684684554, tensor_name="input_example_tensor:0", tensor_type=DT_STRING, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()
    at org.tensorflow.Session.run(Native Method)
    at org.tensorflow.Session.access$100(Session.java:48)
    at org.tensorflow.Session$Runner.runHelper(Session.java:285)
    at org.tensorflow.Session$Runner.run(Session.java:235)
    at tensorflow.HelloTF.main(HelloTF.java:35)
```

Comment: So, you could not get Saver to create a recognizable model in your Python code?  I generate .data and .meta files from a Saver instead of the .pbtxt which you mention.

Comment: I have solve the problem ... answer 2. Also I have been able  to load(in Java ) keras models saved in  .pbtxt.  the trick is to see the graph  using tensorboard to extract the right names of the input and outputs tensors. ...

Answer (score 3):

Ok I finally Solve : the main problem was the name of the input to use in java that is ""dnn/input_from_feature_columns/input_from_feature_columns/concat" and not  "input_example_tensor".

I have discover this using the graph navigation with: tensorboard --logdir=D:\python\Workspace\Autoencoder\src\dnn\ModelSave

here is the java code :

```
public class HelloTF {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SavedModelBundle bundle=SavedModelBundle.load("/java/workspace/APIJavaSampleCode/tfModels/dnn/ModelSave","serve");
    Session s = bundle.session();

    double[] inputDouble = {1.0,0.7982741870963959,1.0,-0.46270838239235024,0.040320274521029376,0.443451913224413,-1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,0.36689718911339564,-0.13577379160035796,-0.5162916256414466,-0.03373651520104648,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.786999801054777,-0.43856035121103853,-0.8199093927945158,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-0.1134921695894473,-1.0,0.6420892436196663,0.7871737734493178,1.0,0.6501788845358409,1.0,1.0,1.0,-0.17586627413625022,0.8817194210401085};
    float [] inputfloat=new float[inputDouble.length];
    for(int i=0;i<inputfloat.length;i++)
    {
        inputfloat[i]=(float)inputDouble[i];
    }
FloatBuffer.wrap(inputfloat) );
    float[][] data= new float[1][35];
    data[0]=inputfloat;
    Tensor inputTensor=Tensor.create(data);


    Tensor result = s.runner()
            .feed("dnn/input_from_feature_columns/input_from_feature_columns/concat", inputTensor)
            //.feed("input_example_tensor", inputTensor)
            //.fetch("tensorflow/serving/classify")
            .fetch("dnn/multi_class_head/predictions/probabilities")
            //.fetch("dnn/zero_fraction_3/Cast")
            .run().get(0);


     float[][] m = new float[1][5];
     float[][] vector = result.copyTo(m);
     float maxVal = 0;
     int inc = 0;
     int predict = -1;
     for(float val : vector[0]) 
     {
         System.out.println(val+"  ");
         if(val > maxVal) {
             predict = inc;
             maxVal = val;
         }
         inc++;
     }
     System.out.println(predict);



}
```

}

I have tested the output :

phyton side :

```
Prediction for sample_2 is:[3] 
Prediction for sample_2 is:[array([ 0.17157166,  0.24475774,  0.16158019,  0.24648622,  0.17560424], dtype=float32)]
```

Java Side :

```
0.17157166  
0.24475774  
0.16158019   
0.24648622  
0.17560424  
3
```

Comment: by the way the NNNormalizeData-out.csv is a 35 inputs and 1 output with 5 classes "0", "1", "2","3","4". 

it is about financial time series and 0 is strong down , 1- weak down - 2 neutral , 3 and 4 for up... Now I can concentrate on the model itself :-)

Answer (score 1):

The error message offers a clue: the tensor named `"input_example_tensor"` in the model expects to have `string` contents, whereas you provided `float` values.

Judging by the name of the tensor and your code, I'd guess that the tensor you're feeding is [defined in `input_fn_utils.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/866087d2257dc80695a29a04d48b2331570fe819/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/utils/input_fn_utils.py#L77). This tensor is passed to the [`tf.parse_example()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/parse_example) op, which expects a vector of [`tf.train.Example`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/example/example.proto) protocol buffers, serialized as strings.

Comment: You can see the code used to create the model in python the inputs are defined as follows :

    feature_columns = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("", dimension=train_inputs.shape[1],dtype=tf.float32)]

Comment: So what should I do ? send a string with the floats separated by commas ?

Comment: If you are indeed using what @mrry pointed out, then as he said it expects a serialized `tf.train.Example` protocol buffer.  If you're using Maven, then you can use the [org.tensorflow:proto](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.tensorflow%7Cproto%7C1.1.0-rc2%7Cjar) package to get all the protocol buffers and construct and serialize the example (see [javadoc](http://static.javadoc.io/org.tensorflow/proto/1.1.0-rc2/org/tensorflow/example/Example.html))

Comment: I just download the tensorflow jar and dll no maven ... (dont know what to do with that links) I will look for a .jar of that org.tensorflow:proto

it is hard to believe nobody try to run a model created with DNNClassifier in java ... there is nothing on the internet. 

Just found people asking. I am stuck with this problem for two weeks many other issue have been overcome (like getting a saved_model.pbtxt with DNNClassifier... Some example I think it would be a page with lots of visitors :-) )

Comment: The Java support is very new, and we're still adding features to it! Unfortunately the JAR doesn't include the necessary code to create an `Example` proto. The easiest option might be to download the [`example.proto`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/example/example.proto) source and run the Protobuf compiler on it to generate the necessary Java classes.

Comment: I have download the jar from here :

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/tensorflow/proto/1.1.0-rc2/

and add as external JAR

but when I add the line import org.tensorflow.framework.TensorProto;  I get a classpath error on eclipse ...

with out using maven it is impossible to execute the model in java ?

Comment: Ok I started with maven and I have a maven project running tensorflow jar and Proto ... The java code I posted is running there and the proto classes ok to use there also. 

Now I do not know what to do with proto so the example is processed in 
Tensor result = s.runner()
                .feed("input_example_tensor", inputTensor)
                .fetch("dnn/multi_class_head/predictions/probabilities")
                .run().get(0);
   ?

Answer (score 0):

I got an error without `feed("input_example_tensor", inputTensor)` on Tensorflow 1.1.

But I found that `example.proto` can be fed as "input_example_tensor", although it took a lot of time to figure out how to create string tensors for serialized protocol buffer.

This is how I created `inputTensor`.

```
org.tensorflow.example.Example.Builder example = org.tensorflow.example.Example.newBuilder();   
/* set some features to example... */

Tensor exampleTensor = Tensor.create(example.build().toByteArray());
// Here, the shape of exampleTensor is not specified yet.

// Set the shape to feed this as "input_example_tensor"
Graph g = bundle.graph(); 
Output examplePlaceholder =
                  g.opBuilder("Placeholder", "example")
                  .setAttr("dtype", exampleTensor.dataType())                        
                      .build().output(0);
Tensor shapeTensor = Tensor.create(new long[]{1}, IntBuffer.wrap(new int[]{1}));                      
Output shapeConst = g.opBuilder("Const", "shape")
                      .setAttr("dtype", shapeTensor.dataType())
                      .setAttr("value", shapeTensor)
                      .build().output(0);
Output shaped = g.opBuilder("Reshape", "output").addInput(examplePlaceholder).addInput(shapeConst).build().output(0);


Tensor inputTensor = s.runner().feed(examplePlaceholder, exampleTensor).fetch(shaped).run().get(0);                   
// Now, inputTensor has shape of [1] and ready to feed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parameters in .feed() and .fetch() should be matching with your input and output datatype.

You can look at your savedmodel.pbtxt file. There are details about your paramaters and their input/output types.

For instance,

my java code

```
Tensor result = s.runner()
        .feed("ParseExample/ParseExample", inputTensor)
        .fetch("dnn/binary_logistic_head/predictions/probabilities")
        .run().get(0);
```

my savedModel.pbtxt (part of it)

```
node {
  name: "ParseExample/ParseExample"
  op: "ParseExample"
  input: "input_example_tensor"
  input: "ParseExample/ParseExample/names"
  input: "ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_0"
  input: "ParseExample/Const"
  attr {
    key: "Ndense"
    value {
      i: 1
    }
  }
  attr {
    key: "Nsparse"
    value {
      i: 0
    }
  }
  attr {
    key: "Tdense"
    value {
      list {
        type: DT_FLOAT
      }
    }
  }
  attr {
    key: "_output_shapes"
    value {
      list {
        shape {
          dim {
            size: -1
          }
          dim {
            size: 2
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  attr {
    key: "dense_shapes"
    value {
      list {
        shape {
          dim {
            size: 2
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  attr {
    key: "sparse_types"
    value {
      list {
      }
    }
  }
}
  outputs {
    key: "scores"
    value {
      name: "dnn/binary_logistic_head/predictions/probabilities:0"
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      tensor_shape {
        dim {
          size: -1
        }
        dim {
          size: 2
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

They both compatible with my datatype, float.

Comment: same answer as bellow (with complete code)... if you have big and more complex models it is hard to find the names in the .pbtxt file. It is easier to use tensorboard and look at the graph ...